# how to determine what type of data in each colum_1 is before putting it in isnull

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select t1.cod_id,
     case when isnull(t1.colum_1,'')=isnull(t2.colum_1,'') then 'ok' else 'error' end colum_1,
     case when isnull(t1.colum_2,'')=isnull(t2.colum_2,'') then 'ok' else 'error' end colum_2,
     case when isnull(t1.colum_3,'')=isnull(t2.colum_3,'') then 'ok' else 'error' end colum_3,
     ...
     ...
     ...
     case when isnull(t1.colum_n,'')=isnull(t2.colum_n,'') then 'ok' else 'error' end colum_n,

from BD_1.MyTable t1 (nolock)
     inner join BD_2.MyTable t2 (nolock)
         on(t1.cod_id=t2.cod_id)

where t1.year='2009' and t1.mounth='05'
```

It is a query that I set it to determine if the data of the records coincided in each column between two tables that are in different databases, but that these are identical in structure and denomination, but not in the number of records, since That the second is only a summary of the first. Of doing so I would throw an `ok`otherwise an `error`, but I ran into the fields that were `null`, These boxes marked `error` even though its equivalent of the other table was also Another `null`, that's why I decide to use `isnull` according to a script I saw on the internet. But the execution of this code gave me the following error:

```
Mens. 8114, Nivel 16, Estado 5, Línea 2
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

It is an error that points to `t1.cod_id` after`select`, the reason I do not know, I suggest in my work that I first make sure to determine what type of field are the columns I am comparing to replace them with a `'*'` If it is string, and with a `'-1'`in case it is numeric, so that (") is not ambiguous or something similar, and then make the comparison.

The point is how I determine what type of data each `colum_1` is before putting it in`isnull`, you may have to use an `IF` although I do not see how.

Note: The cod_id's dataType is `int`

Comment: Change the `ISNULL(Column, '')` to `ISNULL(Column, -9999)` or some other nonsense value for your data.

Comment: shouldn't there be a comma after your asterisk?

Comment: Yes, I already corrected it. But in case it is a string ?, the -9999 no longer works, does it?

Comment: @Fran.J Correct.  Never quote numeric values.  It adds unnecessary conversions for the server to perform.  If it's a `VARCHAR` use `''`, if it's numeric, don't.  You know the datatypes of your columns, so use them the way they're intended to be used.

Comment: I am new to sql server, I do not understand why the problem was generated, if the fields of the tables in comparison are identical, both tables are identical, they are twin. The only difference is that they are in different DBs and the second one has much less records. That is why the conflict caused me many doubts. Also the problem is that there are a lot of columns, more than 280.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch the `when`s from

```
case when isnull(t1.colum_1,'')=isnull(t2.colum_1,'') the 'ok' ...
```

to

```
case when t1.colum_1=t2.colum_1 or (t1.colum_1 is null and t2.colum_1 is null) then 'ok' ...
```

Note: you are missing the 'n' in `then` in your above code as well as the comma after the asterisk `*`.

Comment: Would this line go after `WHEN`?

Comment: @Fran.J No, instead of the `when`.

Answer (score 0):

```
isnull(t1.colum_1,'')
```

Will produce this error:

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

If `colum_1` is a numeric type.  The datatypes of both arguments in `isnull` must be the same.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but the second argument should be implicitly convertible to the first argument's datatype, as in `declare @i numeric; select isnull(@i, '0');`

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes here

`select * t1.cod_id,` should be `select *, t1.cod_id,...`

```
 case when isnull(t1.colum_1,'')=isnull(t2.colum_1,'') the 'ok' else 'error' end colum_1,
```

should be

```
 case when isnull(t1.colum_1,'') and isnull(t2.colum_1,'') then 'ok' else 'error' end as colum_1,
```

If it's a numeric column then

```
 case when isnull(t1.colum_1, 0) and isnull(t2.colum_1,0) then 'ok' else 'error' end as colum_1,
```

Comment: the problem is than i have a lot of columns, more of 281. Specify for each one is very complicated. are there others form?